# Custom Text Box control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a specific need to control how some text is entered in a multiline textbox (ASP:TextBox)

At first I though I could control it with just JavaScript but it appears I can get close but not 100% of what I need.

Now I'm wondering if I need to write a control from scratch (never done that) or if I can inherit from TextBox and be able to get what I need.

**Requirements:**

> 1. MultiLine TextBox
> 2. Ability to control row's and columns
> 3. Would prefer to be able to turn off the scroll bar that appears disabled
>      on a MultiLine Textbox
> 4. Still be able to use the validators
> 5. Word Wrap
> 6. Maxlength
> 7. If I set the columns to 26 and the rows to 4 the user should not be able
>      to enter more then 104 characters
>      (Here comes the parts I've not figured
>      out)
> 8. The user can not enter more then 4 lines even if the max length is not
>      reached.

The 4 line limit has really been the biggest part of my trouble.

If you enter:

> a
>   b
>   c
>   d

I can check how many `\n` characters.  However if you enter:

> 12345678901234567890123456
>   7890
>   c
>   d

Here they have wrapped so there is one less `\n` character or you enter:

> This is a long piece of
>   text that has been entered
>   c
>   d

Here the text has wored wrapped and again you can't just count the `\n` characters.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You can use the `blockquote` and `code` buttons in the editor to format your question - they're just above the edit window.  Also, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting questions.

Comment: Do you want to validate this (and show a validation error if the text does not correspond to your rules) or do you want to prevent the user entering invalid text? But in either case, if you want to do this on the client side in javascript, it is not entirely clear why you need to implement a new server side control for this and how these two things relate? Showing the "almost working" JS code would be also helpful.

Comment: Yes I will be doing client side validation.  The validation is they can't have more the 4 lines and they can't have more tehn 104 characters.

Comment: Is the validation to display an error message, prevent typing or to simply chop the text?

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string by '\n' into an array.
2. Calculate the length divided by 26 (round down and then add 1) for each array member
3. Sum these figures (store as total) (but subtract 1 because the algorithm counts one too many lines due to the last entry)
4. Take the last array member length mod 26. (store as len1)
5. Number of chars left to type = 104 - ((total*26) + len1)

I can come up with some javascript for you if you wish, but are you wanting to display an error message, trim the text, or prevent typing (what are you doing about cut+paste?)

Example Page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function validateTextArea(text) {
                var myText = text.val();
                var myArray = text.val().split("\n");
                var rowcount = myArray.length;
                for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    rowcount += myArray[i].length / 26;
                }
                rowcount -= 1;
                var len1 = myArray[myArray.length - 1].length % 26;
                var charsleft = 104 - ((rowcount * 26) + len1);
                if (charsleft < 0) alert("TOO LONG!");
            }




        </script>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="26" id="txt"></textarea>
        <button onclick='validateTextArea($("#txt"))'>Do Validate</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the ASP:TextBox with Wrap="true" doesn't put hard '\n' when the text wraps.  So the above will not work.

Comment: Yes thats why each row is divided by 26 so if its wrapped it adds an extra row count

Comment: Yes thats why each row is divided by 26 so if its wrapped it adds an extra row count so with your example 2 - split into 3 strings by \n (there are 2 * '\n' = 3 entries).  First row 30/26 = 1 (rounded down) so add one, entries 2 and 3 lengths/26=0 so total = 1+3 - 1 = 3 rows.  len1 = 1 mod 26 = 1. Number of chars left to type = 104 - (26*3 + 1) = 104 - 79 = 25....